# How can I change the Unity launcher delay in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: unity, launcher

I know this question has been asked before, but I cannot adjust the delay in Ubuntu 13.04 following the older suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

use Ubuntu tweak tool so there you can configure your unity as you want.To install it

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

then open it from unity dash by typing as **ubuntu-tweak**